# Bridge design pattern implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have created one example for bridge design pattern. is it correct way to implement this or there is something I missed it?

**Scenario** : there is abstraction class Home which have abstract method paint implement by concreate classes(Flat and Apartment) and paint is another abstract class which having abstract method of paint(to paint the house). and one enum for color pickup.

```
abstract class Home {
      private String homeType;
      private Paint paint;
      
      public Home(String type, Paint paint) {
          this.homeType = type;
          this.paint = paint;
      }

      abstract void paintTheHome();

      public String getHomeType() {
          return homeType;
      }
      
      public Paint getPaint() {
          return paint;
      }
}


public class Flat extends Home{
  public static final String Type="Flat";
  
  public Flat(Paint paint) {
      super(Type,paint);
  }

  @Override
  void paintTheHome() {
      getPaint().paint(this);
  }

}


public class Apartment extends Home {
  public static final String Type="Apartment";
      
      Apartment(Paint paint){
          super(Type,paint);
      }

      @Override
      void paintTheHome() {
          getPaint().paint(this);
      }
}

public abstract class Paint {
  private Color color;
  private String brand;
  
  public Paint(Color color, String brand) {
          this.color=color;
          this.brand = brand;
  }
  
  public Color getColor() {
      return color;
  }
  public String getBrand() {
      return brand;
  }
  
  abstract void paint(Home home);
  
}


public class AsianPaint extends Paint{
  public static final String brand = "Asian Paint";
  
  public AsianPaint(Color color) {
      super(color,brand);
  }

  @Override
  void paint(Home home) {
      System.out.println("Painting Started for "+home.getHomeType());
      System.out.println("Brand of Color"+this.getBrand());
      System.out.println("Name of Color"+this.getColor());
      System.out.println("painting Ended");
  }

}


public class ShalimarPaint extends Paint{
  public static final String brand = "Shalimar Paint";
  
  public ShalimarPaint(Color color) {
      super(color,brand);
  }

  @Override
  void paint(Home home) {
      System.out.println("Painting Started for "+home.getHomeType());
      System.out.println("Brand of Color"+this.getBrand());
      System.out.println("Name of Color"+this.getColor());
      System.out.println("painting Ended");
  }

}


public enum Color {
      RED("Red"),
      GREEN("Green"),
      BLUE("Blue"),
      WHITE("White"),
      YELLOW("Yellow");
  
      String colorName;
  
      Color(String string) {
          this.colorName = string;
      }
      
      String getColor(){
          return colorName;
      }
}


public class client {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
          Home home = new Apartment(new AsianPaint(Color.RED));
          home.paintTheHome();
          
          home = new Flat(new ShalimarPaint(Color.GREEN));
          home.paintTheHome();
          
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do. You should be precise when asking a question. You talk about pattern but I seem to see simple inheritance. Can you clearly name the pattern you're trying to implement ? Is it strategy pattern? If so you should add a setter for Paint member. The logic in `paintTheHome()` is common to every implementation so I'd not make it `abstract` and put the logic in `Home`.

Comment: hope it would be clear now @UchiTesting

Comment: Thank you for the precision. Behavioural patterns are the ones I understand the least to date and I may be wrong but.
Structurally Strategy and Bridge are very common in that they both have a member of an interface type. The difference is the intent.
It looks correct for what I can tell. So your abstraction is paint which in turn may have different facets such as brand and color and you could add other facets such as texture or more. I'd maybe export the brand (and other facets) in it's own hierarchy though but that's fair enough for that demo.

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency between the two abstractions: `Home` and `Paint`. This indicates one level of abstraction. The Bridge pattern links two levels of abstraction with a dependency from a high-level abstraction to a low-level abstraction. Here you have two high-level abstractions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to understand this pattern I created this scenario. I just want to know whether the implementation is correct or not? @Community